# How and when do updates to a package like mariadb get rolled out?

Tags: apt, updates, mariadb

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 which is fully patched / updated.
I am running Mariadb 10.6.7 which installed via the included repos.

10.6.7 contains some horrible fundamental bugs like the database stops returning queries after a while on large tables without running analyse all the time.

The current version of 10.6 is 10.6.10 which is september 2022.  Why do I not see that when I type update/upgrade?  What is the best way to install that version from where I am right now?

Comment: Not really, because I know they don't include bleeding edge, that makes sense and I'm glad of it.  However, its opaque to me and as there is a horrible show stopping issue in the version it does have - that approach is no good for me.  So my question becomes best way to install 10.6.10 from here right now?  I find posts about adding this keyring to that dodgy URL etc. but I wanted to know the best way.  Its a container that I can try and throw away no problem.

Comment: The general rule of thumb for Ubuntu packages; is that security fixes get backported to the released version. There are exceptions; where it's more work to backport security fixes, than just re-package the later release of the program, test it etc; but that is rare given the testing overhead required. Your question does not mention other sources (*comments are for us to query or get details from you, but your additional details or changes should be reflected in your question*)   Also fyi:  when there are newer packages you'll find *change posts*, as it goes against the *stable* release model

Comment: Does anyone else knows about those "horrible fundamental bugs"? Are there bug reports with links you can share? Have they been fixed. IMHO, if you have to ask "what is the best way", then it is best to pay someone to do it for you.

Comment: "So my question becomes best way to install 10.6.10 from here right now? " That is asking for opinions... and when it comes to opinions the answer is: whatever works for you ;) I myself have ALL of my SQL servers in `/opt/`. Why not do the same? Install the one you want -from source- into `/opt/` (it will be `/opt/mariadb-{version}/` and you can keep adding new versions to `/opt/`.

Comment: why don't you install docker an run mariadb in a container? Version 10.8.5 is present on docker Hub.

Comment: I don't have to justify my reasoning.  however, https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28073 causes queries to lock up, locking the table and bringing us down.  It basically stops using the indexes until you call analyze an immediate fix (so have it on daily bodge script).  Their persistent table statistics were found to not be persistent enough causing the optimiser to get stuck, can't fix the query if it stops using the indexes.  The bug means that if you migrate from a previous version your statistics can remain static and never update.  For me, I just want to have an option.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks - this is the most sensible suggestion.  And you're right about opinions, especially Linux forums.  Like "why do you do your entire thing my way2, etc.  Its whatever works for you not just because the place is littered with half finished partially working bodgeware but also because we're time poor and 80% of what I have to work with is inherited.  At least I went to ask what is the best way to get to that version without creating an even bigger rats nest of spaghetti configs.

Comment: @dummyuser its already a container - which is puppet controlled.  However, I did look at 10.8.5. because of another bug which is to do with running mariadb on zfs, creating a FS snapshot can break running queries, issue fixed in 10.8.something but I think backported to 10.6.something else hence why I was aiming for 10.6.10.

Comment: The rule of thumb suggests updates find their way into the 6 monthly build.  Well its 6 months from 22.04 and it hasn't and I'd no doubt be disappointed to find out that the version that does end up in that would be itself 5 months old.  Although I like to try to stay as close to the release builds as possible.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You use containers, means your release management for mariadb is fully independent from Ubuntu as you complain about ubuntu Release management?

Answer (score 3):

Most (not all) deb packages are merged from Debian every six months. The merge happens a couple months before release. So if you want to look at a package history, Debian is a good place to look.

Let's see what the Debian Package Tracker (tracker.debian.org), says about `mariadb-server` (https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/mariadb-10.6) in October 2022.

[image]

You can see that Debian has packaged newer releases. But check those dates against the [Ubuntu deadline for inclusion](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/kinetic-kudu-release-schedule/27263) into 22.10:

[image]

10.6.9 was migrated into Ubuntu 22.10 (check apt on a 22.10 system: It's there). It's now eligible for [backporting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) to earlier releases (like 22.04).

10.6.10 was a month too late. It --or some other newer release-- will be included in the next release of Ubuntu: 23.04, to be released in April 2023. After release, it will become eligible for backporting.

Of course, if you really MUST be running the *newest* versions, then LTS might be the wrong path for you. LTS is not meant for that use case.

- LTS is meant for enterprises that want minimal changes and no breaking changes, and are willing to run fully-patched but older versions.
- Folks who want newer versions of software should consider the 6-month interim releases of Ubuntu.
- The hybrid model --installing newer software onto an LTS "base"-- can be problematic. It tends to be built upon false assumptions and to offer the worst of both worlds instead of the best. If it were a great solution, it would be released that way.